# Which domain (domains supported by siri kit) does my application fall into and which intent to use to implement siri?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, siri, sirikit

I was just trying to implement siri kit in my application. Our application is a travel based app where you can search holiday packages for a specific destination and there would be some deals on offering. we want to implement siri to search a particular destination or a particular deals. For example “Get me the list of hotels for caribbean using < My App name>”.  So i was wondering to which domain (the domains that support siri kit) my application falls and which intent to use it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1) SiriKit supports these features for now, I think these will be updated in future

- VoIP calling
- Messaging
- Payments
- Photos
- Workouts
- Ride booking
- Car commands
- CarPlay (automotive vendors only)
- Restaurant reservations (requires additional support from Apple)

For now, Apple controls intent domains, and doesn't allow developers to define new intent domains.

Comment: As I understand, we cannot create a custom domain, we can only create custom requests for existing domains as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Siri is not supported your requirement. Please read the apple documentation about siri Intents.

Comment: Everybody knows Apple documentation includes almost all answers about iOS questions. Please provide reference link, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same question; take a look at [ Custom Intents](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/siri/overview/custom-intents/), which provides the flexibility you need.